# Passing the Maven Debug Flag from Hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I'm having an issue with a maven build in hudson.  This issue would be fairly easy to resolve if I could see the output of maven with the -X flag passed in.  However I can't find a way to do this.  If I specify "-X" in the "Goals and options" field of the "Build" section in the job configuration my console output looks exactly the same as if I had not passed the "-X" flag at all.  Is the debug logging going somewhere else?  Or is there some other way I need to pass the "-X" flag?

UPDATE:

The reason this isn't working is because the build is failing during the "Parsing POMs" part of the hudson process, before it actually kicks off the true maven build and passes in any params I specify in the project.  So what I really need is a way to get better logging during the "Parsing POMs" part of a maven build in hudson.

Answer (score 11):

That's what it says in the help text.

> Specifies the goals to execute, such
>   as "clean install" or "deploy". This
>   field can also accept any other
>   command line options to Maven, such as
>   "-e" or "-Dmaven.test.skip=true".

I would have put it there as well.

The maven help gives me the following two options:

```
 -X,--debug                    Produce execution debug output
 -e,--errors                   Produce execution error messages
```

May be you can try the --debug or the -e swtich

Comment: I have tried this before (and just tried again)  but get no additional output.  Seems like it should work, but its not.  If I run this same build directly from the command line with -X or --debug, I do get a lot of additional information.  However the specific issue i'm trying to solve is only occurring when the build is run from hudson.

Comment: Put an additional build step (batch or shell script) and run the set command. Compare the output with the output from a set command issued manually from the command line. This may help you to see if there is a difference between the environment variables that Hudson sees and your command line environment variables. The path variable has a huge influence in some cases. -- I hope I am right with the assumption that you run the command line test with the same user account than Hudson runs under.

Answer (score 6):

In Jenkins, and I assume this is true for Hudson as well, command line arguments can be passed to Maven in the "goals" setting.  I was able to pass the -X parameter by adding it to the beginning of the "goals".

```
-X package install
```

Jenkins apparently blindly appends this setting to the end of the mvn command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with Hudson 1.398 (Maven 2.0.10, jdk 1.6.0_07): the build fails during the parsing of the pom files. It works locally and when launched manually from the Hudson workspace.

That build needs an environment variable to be set (for the path of a module), but the environment variable doesn't seem to be propagated from Hudson to Maven. So, like you, I have also tried to get more details from Maven with the -X option, but it also doesn't seem to be propagated.