# Maven Deploy : Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase:Conflict

Tags: maven-3, artifact

I am trying to deploy our project artifact i.e. jar file to a remote repo which I have access to.

Below are the steps which I have done but am getting error when trying to deploy the jar,

1. Created settings-security.xml in local m2 repo and created encrypted master password.
2. Use distributionManagement in pom.xml to deploy the artifact to repo. Specified the id, name and url for the repo under repository tag.
3. Put the same id in my settings.xml and provided my sid and svn password (encrypted). I have write access to repo (verified by uploading the jar using tortoise client).

Now, when I try to deploy, I get conflict exception. Below is the error,

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file
>   (default-cli) on project : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not
>   transfer artifact abc:jar:1.0.0 from/to abc-repo (url):

Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase:Conflict.

Comment: Maybe you can find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734788/maven-deploydeploy-file-fails-409-conflict-yet-artifact-uploads-successfully) post useful to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had gone through this post, didnt fit in my issue.

Comment: In my case, Apache Archiva had not the correct rights to access the repository (read access was OK but write access was KO) which prevented me to deploy files due to 409 error.