# Error while deploying project on SVN server

Tags: maven, pom.xml, visualsvn-server

While deploying my project on SVN server I get an error. I tried every possible way, but still facing the same.
The error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:  
2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project kedb: Failed to deploy artifacts:  
Could not transfer artifact com.kedb:kedb:jar:0.0.1-20140928.140840-1 
from/to unique: Failed to transfer 
/com/kedb/kedb/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/kedb-0.0.1-20140928.140840-1.jar. 
Error code 409, Conflict -> [Help 1]
```

What is the solution for this? What can be the issue?

Comment: You're deploying artefacts not to a Maven repository but to... an SVN server?! Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven deploy:deploy-file fails (409 Conflict), yet artifact uploads successfully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734788/maven-deploydeploy-file-fails-409-conflict-yet-artifact-uploads-successfully)

Comment: thanks @kaqqao, I wanna deploy the built on SVN server,On local system the I can get the built but its not getting deploy on my SVN Server.

Comment: Also in the link you provided the artifact is getting deployed successfully. But I my case the artifact is not at all getting deployed on the svn server.Also the SVN server I am using is 'VISUAL SVN server'.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is a version control system and has no direct relation to Maven, which is a build tool. Maven deploys built artifacts to Maven repositories. In SVN you normally commit your sources, not binary artifacts. While it is probably possible to commit the produced artifacts automatically using the [SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html), you shoul probably explain better if this is really what you need.

Comment: When i execute the same goal, with local file system path as location of remote repository in distribution management tag ,it works fine.

Comment: Yes, you made a local Maven repo (a folder, really) and deployed there. Same would work with a remote repo if you give it a usable protocol (like scp or sftp), but that has nothing to do with SVN. Re-read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below logs for the successful attempt using remote repository as local file system path

INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ KEDB ---
    Downloading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (762 B at 74.4     KB/sec)
    Uploading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/KEDB-0.0.1-20141005.132612-2.war
    Uploaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/KEDB-0.0.1-20141005.132612-2.war (123 KB at 1205.4 KB/sec)
    Uploading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/KEDB-0.0.1-20141005.132612-2.pom
    Uploaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/KEDB-0.0.1-20141005.132612-2.pom (2 KB at 1418.9 KB/sec)
    Downloading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/maven-metadata.xml (272 B at 66.4 KB/sec)
    Uploading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    Uploaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (762 B at 372.1 KB/sec)
    Uploading: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/maven-metadata.xml
    Uploaded: file:///E:/itworkshere/com/kedb/KEDB/maven-metadata.xml (272 B at 265.6 KB/sec)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.082s 
    [INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 05 01:26:12 GMT-12:00 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/20M
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------