# Deploy SNAPSHOT to oss.jfrog.org (JCenter)

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, bintray, ojo

I tried doing a `mvn deploy` for oss.jfrog.org for my project. However I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://oss.jfrog.org/simple/oss-snapshot-local/com/myorg/mylibrary/com/myorg/mylibrary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mylibrary-0.0
.1-20141211.050111-1.pom. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:573)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:493)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:474)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:871)
        ... 28 more
```

When I look into the JFrog Repository Browser, I can see that the jar is there withe the correct version, what could be this error, and why is the jar deployed anyway even with this error?

Here's my POM setting:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>bintray-myorg-maven-mylibrary</id>
        <name>artifactory-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/simple/oss-snapshot-local/com/myorg/mylibrary/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Could it be because of the `bintray-*` id?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734788/maven-deploydeploy-file-fails-409-conflict-yet-artifact-uploads-successfully  
Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`simple` shouldn't be a part of your URL. 
Artifactory thinks that `simple` is the name of the repository and `oss-snapshot-local` is a part of your `groupId`. Since pom shows a different `groupId`, it fails with 409.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I managed to get it uploading with having the '<url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local</url>' and the id same as with the maven settings.xml