# Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase:Conflict (JCenter)

Tags: java, maven, bintray

I have a artificact deployed in JCenter (oss.jfrog.org) although the deployment did not end without error (see [Deploy SNAPSHOT to oss.jfrog.org (JCenter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415722/deploy-snapshot-to-oss-jfrog-org-jcenter)), the jars are there when I check the Repository browser.

Now I add the dependency in a project for this artifact (library) and adding:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- Release repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Snapshot repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory-snapshots</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When maven started building, it throws this error:

`Failed to transfer file: http://oss.jf
rog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/myorg/mylibrary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mylibrary-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase:Conflict. -> [Help 1]`

for the dependency I added. What could be the problem here?

Comment: In my case, Apache Archiva had not the correct rights to access the repository (read access was OK but write access was KO) which prevented me to deploy files due to 409 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the virtual repositories

```
 <repositories>
    <!-- Release repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Snapshot repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory-snapshots</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a **workaround**. No idea why, but in my case adding shade plugin to all modules solved the problem, even an empty one:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                </artifactSet>
                <relocations>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```